# Importing column from one shapefile to another using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

So I have two shapefiles: one is a hexbinned shapefile with data of how many dogs, cats, and birds in it and another with county lines.

How would I merge the two shapefiles to show which county each hex bin is in? I've tried the following query

```
create table newhex AS (select * from hexes, counties where ST_Within(hexes.geom, counties.geom));
```

but I get the error `Error executing user query: ERROR:  column "gid" specified more than once`

I'm assuming that there are two difference geom columns and that conflicted the geom columns. So I tried another query with explicit selecting the the geom column of the hex bin and the county name with:

```
select shp_ohhexsm.geom, ohcounties.name from shp_ohhexsm, ohcounties where ST_Within(shp_ohhexsm.geom, ohcounties.geom)
```

But I get this weird result

[image]

Is there any way I can just merge the name of the counties into my hex files without the weird spaces?

Comment: Nothing weird about that result -- It's the logical outcome of a WITHIN test.  You've got multiple questions in this question. Since the "star" selection resulting in duplicate column names isn't GIS-related, I recommend you focus on the correct spatial relation test (ST_Intersects), which will produce a different kind of error (boundary cells being selected twice).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two issues that you need to consider:

1. Your small hexagonal polygons are still polygons and can overlay two county polygons, with ST_Within returning `false`. You will probably want to reduce these hexagonal polygons to a point, e.g. the centroid. This can be achieved with the `ST_Centroid` function.
2. The join itself based on geographic location which can be solved with a join statement as follows:

   ```
   SELECT * 
   FROM hexes H LEFT OUTER JOIN counties C 
   ON ST_Within(ST_Centroid(H.geom), C.geom);
   ```

   The left outer join makes sure you don't drop any hexagonal polygon where the centroid might be outside of your county geometries, by returning a `NULL` value.

The last problem you need to solve is related to the `CREATE TABLE AS ...` statement where you cannot have two identical column names. You need to list your columns manually and you might need to rename a column with the `col_name AS new_name` syntax like here:

```
SELECT H.gid AS gid_hex, C.gid AS gid_county
FROM ...
```

(assuming the same query as before and you have two `gid` columns, and you want to keep both of them).

Comment: I've tried running your query as

 ```CREATE TABLE hexnew AS SELECT H.gid as hexid, C.gid as cid, cats, dogs, birds FROM hextable H LEFT OUTER JOIN countytable C ON
 ST_Within(ST_Centroid(H.geom), C.geom));``` 

and I get the right table, however, when I run it on pgsql2shp, I only get  a .dbf. It appears the error that's causing this is ```NOTICE:  gserialized_gist_joinsel: jointype 1 not supported```. Any thoughts?

Comment: You will need to include the H.geom in the columns to select, otherwise there is no geometry in your result.